# Hyperlinks.Follow error: Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

After I activate the hyperlink I get the subscript out of range at the sheet selection line

```
'Hyperlink aktivieren und Sheet Overview Results
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=True, AddHistory:=True
Worksheets("Overview Results").Select
AuswerteWb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'ActiveWindow.Close
```

The thing is that I have a macro which should use a path of a file as hyperlink and select the sheet "overview Results" from the hyperlinked file.

But I get

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Did You set `Option Base 1` ?

Comment: This error can occur when you reference a sheet name that does not exist. Double check the sheet name and check for leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Why use `Hyperlinks.Follow` and not `Workbooks.Open`? If you are opening a new workbook using the hyperlink you will want to do something like this:

```
Dim OpenedFile as Workbook

' Skip any errors that would occur with a null link
On Error Resume Next
Set OpenedFile = Workbooks.Open(Selection.Value)
On Error GoTo 0

' Ensure that the file is set before operating on it
If Not OpenedFile Is Nothing Then
    Dim TargetWorksheet as Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set TargetWorksheet = OpenedFile.Worksheets("Overview Results")
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' We use the same Nothing check before operating on the worksheet
    If Not TargetWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        TargetWorksheet.Activate
    End If
End If

AuswerteWb = OpenedFile.Name
'ActiveWindow.Close
```

I highly encourage you to learn about qualifying your statements (for example, `Worksheets("")` is an unqualified statement) since this will cause you many headaches. Similarly, avoid `Selection`, `Select`, `Activate`, `ActiveWorkbook`, etc.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark the answer as the correct answer :). I am glad it is working for you.